# XNA close the game

Tags: c#, process, xna, exit

So i'm building a game for fun :) and in specific point I try to close the game.

I found that to close the game I need to use the function Exit() in Game1 so I tried the next code:

```
    Game1.GetInstance().Exit();
```

GetInstance is my own method that return the Game1 instance so I will be able to exit the game from other classes.

How can I close the game from different class? What I did is save the pointer to the game1 instance in the game1 constructor and then I can return it to use it in other classes. I hope it was clear (sorry if not).

So how do I use the exit function from other classes?

Comment: Create an event on the main thread/form to exit and raise it in the class. So the class invokes the event of the main form and the main form exits.

Comment: I've removed your "second question" - as everyone was answering the first one. You should create a separate question for it - with as much detail about it as possible - so it can be answered specifically.

Comment: Also, I don't really get what the problem you are having is. If your `GetInstance()` method works as expected and returns the instance of `Game1`, then the exact code you have there (`Game1.GetInstance().Exit()`) should work from anywhere that is `using` the namespace that contains `Game1`.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a method in your `game1` class

```
public void Quit()
{
    this.Exit();
}
```

Now in your other class you want to exit from, you can add a reference to your main class

```
public class SomeOtherClassYouWantToExitFrom
{
       public Game1 game; //Reference to your main class

       public void DoStuff()
       {
             //Do Stuff
             game.Quit();
       }
}
```

When you create the `SomeOtherClassYouWantToExitFrom` class, you need to set the game object as the Game1 instance. You could also pass it as an argument in the constuctor

```
   Blah = new SomeOtherClassYouWantToExitFrom(...) { game = this };
```

Using the Exit method works fine for me, Im not sure why Visual studio thinks its still debugging.

Answer (score 0):

If Game1 is a singleton it should work, you could always use an enum from Game1, then exit in Game1.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using MonoGame version 3.4, but I stumbled onto this question while I was trying to solve the issue myself...

Here's what I did that works really well (I needed to quit from a class that doesn't exist in Game1)

I noticed Program.cs was already a static class, so I leveraged that:

```
// Program.cs
using System;

namespace XnaGame
{
#if WINDOWS || LINUX
    public static class Program
    {
        public static Game1 Game;

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            using (var game = new Game1())
            {
                Game = game;
                Game.Run();
            }
        }
    }
#endif
}
```

At that point I have access to

```
Program.Game.Exit()
```

from anywhere in my game while still having the benefit of the *using* statement provided.